# iPad/tablet parallax issue

Tags: html, jquery, css

I was just wondering if there were still issues with the parallax effect on mobiles and tablets in 2020? All the articles and questions I have read are a few years old,

Many thanks,

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for https://ux.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've come to tell that there is not an issue with the parallax effect on mobile still. But it's not always gonna be that way because somehow some way someone will find out a way to jack it up make it a problem again.

Comment: Thank you for this! So I can add the css to the mobile first breakpoint?